# java.lang.RuntimeException: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play

I uploaded a new version of my application and I am getting this crash in Google Console, but I don't know what is causing is... Can anyone help?

[image]

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4436)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700 (ActivityThread.java:260)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2147)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:329)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8058)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1026)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags (PendingIntent.java:377)
  at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser (PendingIntent.java:647)
  at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast (PendingIntent.java:634)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.gtm.zzbv.zzfe (zzbv.java:52)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.gtm.zzbv.cancel (zzbv.java:54)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.gtm.zzbv.zzaw (zzbv.java:4)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.gtm.zzan.zzag (zzan.java:7)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.gtm.zzap.<init> (zzap.java:67)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.gtm.zzap.zzc (zzap.java:82)
  at com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver.onReceive (CampaignTrackingReceiver.java:8)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4427)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700 (ActivityThread.java:260)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2147)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:329)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8058)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1026)
```

Comment: Got the same problem, have you found any solution for that?